# node prevent accidentally calling async function without await

Tags: node.js, async-await

Is there a node or vscode feature that will keep me from accidentally forgetting to call my async functions with await? I've done this a few times and it always costs me hours of bug-hunting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [ESlint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await) which warns for async functions which have no await expression.

EDIT:
You need to create '.eslintrc.json' file and add some rules to it. If you installed ESLint globally, you ca do it by  running `eslint --init`. You can find more information in the [vscode plugin github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint).

The availabe rules related to async/await are:

- **no-await-in-loop** - disallow await inside of loops
- **no-return-await** - disallow unnecessary return await
- **require-await** - disallow async functions which have no await expression

You can find more about ESLint and available rules on [the official documentation page](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/).

Comment: This sounds promising. I'm not familiar with eslint. I installed the vscode extension and I did `npm install -g eslint` but I don't notice any difference.

Comment: See my edit for more information on ESLint setup and configuration.

Comment: `require-await` doesn't check each call to see if it should have had an await. It only sees your `async function` and makes sure there's at least 1 `await` inside.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Javascript or the normal ESLint rules because ESLint can not know the type of the expression and thus cannot know when something is a Promise (without executing the code).

If you're using TypeScript, this is possible with the [no-misused-promises](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-misused-promises).

Here's an example where it's especially useful:

```js
const promise = Promise.resolve(false);

if (promise) {
  // Do something
}
```

The missing await causes the if to always happen.